# Count the occurrences of a phrase with GREP

Tags: unix, grep

Count the occurrences of a phrase with GREP

I have a directory containing a bunch of files. So when I need to see if any of the files contains a certain phrase, I'd use

`grep 'the phrase' mydir/*`

Is there any way to count the total number of  times that the phrase appears in these files?

I've used `grep 'the phrase' mydir/* --count`

But that'd give the occurrences in each individual file, not the total, which is not what I want.

Comment: Awk? Perl? Also, you've noticed that grep will miss your phrase if it breaks over lines, right?

Comment: If the phrase breaks over lines, it's a not phrase (in my definition) anymore. So yeah I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find mydir -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'the phrase' | wc -l
```

`find mydir -print0` - finds all the files in mydirectory and prints them as null terminated lines)

`xargs -0` - converts a stream of null terminated lines and converts them into quote seperated arguments, e.g. "mydir/file 1" "mydir/file 2" ... these can now be passed into the arument list of grep.

`wc -l` - counts the number of lines

The null terminated lines business is all to do with working around files that have spaces in them since otherwise these can look like multiple arguments to grep.

Comment: Will only count the number of lines containing the phrase; if it's split across lines or multiple times on one line it will be miscounted.

Comment: That's true although given what the OP said about what's he's tried with grep up to now, that sounds like what he/she wants..

Comment: @Benj: Thanks! That works perfectly. And that's exactly what I need!. But I kind of just copy-and-paste the thing wiithout really undertanding the semantics behind it. What're `-print0`, `xargs -0`, `wc -1` ?

Comment: @OneTwoThree - I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's even simpler than the previous two responses:

```
grep 'the phrase' mydir/* | wc -l
```

The output of grep across all files that match "mydir/*" is then sent to wc -l.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'the phrase' mydir/* --count | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; sum=0;} { sum = sum + $2; } END { print sum } '
```